# About Creating Own Android Market

Tags: google-play

We want to create our own android market (website, server side...), is there any official document we can refer? Is there any open source product/software/framework can help to create android market?

Comment: A search on google led me here :),Why there are no answers or comments

Answer (score 10):

[Aptoide](http://www.aptoide.com/index2.html) is probably what you're looking for. It's an opensource market clone and you can add your own server as a repository.

Comment: How to Download This Market?